# How to make CalendarChart with google in [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony, charts, google-visualization, symfony4

I use CMENGoogleChartsBundle
https://github.com/cmen/CMENGoogleChartsBundle
I have tried the pieChart()

```
$pieChart = new PieChart();
$pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
    //data ..
);
```

Its work

```
$calendar = new Calendar();
$calendar->getData()->setArrayToDataTable();
```

Not work

> I have followed the documentation but i don't understood, because its
>   in js but i need to make it by php like pieChart()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be...

```
$calendar = new CalendarChart();
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample data like,     $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
        [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
         ['Work',     11] ] ); but with $calendar

Comment: from the link you provided --> [calendar-chart](https://github.com/cmen/CMENGoogleChartsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook.md#calendar-chart)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22605572)